# Setup project in Visual Studio 2017 missing vs_setup.msi?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I'm trying to build a set up project for a Windows Forms application, I copied it from a coworker, we use this project (on his machine) to deploy the application.
I installed the setup template in Visual Studio 2017. When I build the project these windows show up, looking for the file in:

```
d:\aaf5ce84f8decdcaf3b2f1\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup\
```

[image]
then this:
[image]

When I click OK, this message appear:

> The file
>   'd:\aaf5ce84f8decdcaf3b2f1\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup\'
>   is not a valid installation for the product Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2010 Shell(Integrated)- ENU..."

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran these commands in  Command Prompt (as adminstrator):

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
```

and

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
```

No Idea what they do, but the problem has been solved!

Comment: Worked for VS 2019 too.

Comment: Solved the same problem that occurred when trying to execute a command-line build of an InstallShield project from either VS2008 or VS2017